# Insert values from textbox into DB2 Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, insert, db2, database-connection

I want to insert value into my table. (Database:-DB2) based on the value obtained by text box. I'm creating a demo page where my text box will get an integer value and on button click it must insert into the database. The issue is there is no such method called `AddWithValue()` when we are dealing with DB2 Connection. **Now how i can obtain value from text box so i can insert into the table??**

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String pass = TextBox4.Text;
            DB2Connection connect = new DB2Connection("Database=SAMPLE;UserID=xxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx;Server=xx.xx.xx.xx:50000");
            DB2Command cmd = new DB2Command();
            cmd.Connection = connect;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Demo VALUES (@pass)";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
            connect.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connect.Close();
        }
```

ERROR 1:

> IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ParameterCollection does not contain a definition for
>   'AddWithValue' and no extension method 'AddWithValue'accepting a first
>   argument of type 'IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ParameterCollection' could be found

Also, On `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` its showing me an error
 ERROR 2:

> {Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation
>   timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function
>   evaluation.}

Comment: what is problem in this ??

Comment: @PranayRana AddWithValue() does not work when we are dealing with DB2 Connetion. It does not get values from the text box and throws error

Comment: @codingbiz IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ParameterCollection does not contain a definition for 'AddWithValue' and no extension method 'AddWithValue'accepting a first argument of type 'IBM.Data.DB2.DB2ParameterCollection' could be found

Comment: check the DB2Paramter Class http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.adonet.ref.doc%2Fdoc%2FDB2ParameterClass.html

Comment: @SearchAndResQ that will help me for sure, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always just setup the parameter using the longer syntax, e.g.

```
 DB2Parameter p1 = new DB2Parameter();
 p1.ParameterName = "@pass";
 p1.DB2Type = DB2Type.Double;
 p1.Value = 2;

 cmd.Parameters.Add(p1);
```

Comment: What do you mean 'not working'? Does it throw an exception, if so what is the exception message. What I posted is just an example of constructing a parameter object, you still need to pass in the correct values for your query.